# Get the titles and URLs of Yahoo result page in c#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I want to get titles and URLs of Yahoo result page with htmlagility pack

```
HtmlWeb w = new HtmlWeb();

string SearchResults = "https://en-maktoob.search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + query.querytxt;

var hd = w.Load(SearchResults);


    var nodes = hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@cite and @href]");
    if (nodes != null)
    {
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {

            {
                string Text = node.Attributes["title"].Value;
                string Href = node.Attributes["href"].Value;

            }
        }
```

It works but all links in search result are not Appropriate links how to omit  ads link , Yahoo links    and etc .
I want to access the correct links

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML source? It's pretty easy to distinguish between search result links and ad links.

Comment: @Rick they are in   `<a class=" ac-algo ac-21th lh-15" ` can u guide me to access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
HtmlWeb w = new HtmlWeb();

string search = "https://en-maktoob.search.yahoo.com/search?p=veverke";
//ac-algo ac-21th lh-15
var hd = w.Load(search);

var titles = hd.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".title a").Select(n => n.InnerText);
var links = hd.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".fz-15px.fw-m.fc-12th.wr-bw.lh-15").Select(n => n.InnerText);

for (int i = 0; i < titles.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    var title = titles.ElementAt(i);
    string link = string.Empty;
    if (links.Count() > i)
        link = links.ElementAt(i);

    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}, Link: {1}", title, link);
}
```

Keep in mind that I am using the extension method `CssSelect`, from nuget package's `ScrapySharp`. Install it just like you installed `HtmlAgilityPack`, then add a using statement at the top of the code like `using ScrapySharp.Extensions;` and you are good to go. (I use it because its easier to refer to `css` selectors instead of `xpath` expressions...)

Regarding skipping ads, I noticed ads in these yahoo search results will come at the last record only ? Assuming I am correct, simply skip the last one.

Here's the output I get for running the code above:

[image]

Comment: it worked tnx a lot. but unfotunately it does  not return the results in order of Yahoo result page.